# Install angular without npm install command

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I'm working in a company with big security restrictions, so I can download and install files, I have nodeJS and npm but I can't make the npm install works. I have tried downloading it from git and running the npm install from the unzipped folder but I get an error :

```
> @angular/devkit-repo@0.0.0 preinstall D:\angular-cli-master
> node ./tools/yarn/check-yarn.js

D:\angular-cli-master\tools\yarn\check-yarn.js:12
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error: Please use Yarn instead of NPM to install dependencies. See: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\angular-cli-master\tools\yarn\check-yarn.js:12:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

I have tried for example to ping 8.8.8.8 or google.com, but it doesn't work (host unreachable) even though I can access google from my browser, I guess because of the firewall. So I can't access external IPs from cmd or powershell terminals.

I would like to know how I can install angular without using the npm install command.

Comment: Have you tried Yarn as suggest in the error ? Do you have access to an http(s) proxy like cntml ?

Comment: yarn isn't recognized, I'll try to install see, if it changes something. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: same problem with yarn, network connectivity issues

Comment: Take a look at http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/ i had to install it to be able to fetch npm package through the corporate proxy (this is because you say : I'm working in a company with big security restrictions)